# Scale issues on chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, scale, logarithm

I have a graph below made in plotly(python). I have set graph y-axis in log scale. but I don't know why there are intermediate values between 1000 and 10k like (2,3,4,5,6...). What they are representing? and how they are removed? I must want to remove.
[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts1Dr.jpg)

The properties of axis are given below

```
trace1 = {
  "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
  "y": [500, 900, 1100, 10000, 300], 
  "marker": {
    "color": 'rgb(255,140,0)', 

  }, 
data = Data([trace1])
layout = {
  "autosize": False, 
  "bargap": 0.0, 
  "height": 480, 
  "hovermode": "closest", 
  "margin": {
    "r": 63, 
    "t": 57, 
    "b": 52, 
    "l": 80, 
    "pad": 0
  }, 
  "showlegend": False,  
  "titlefont": {
    "color": "#000000", 
    "size": 12.0
  }, 
  "width": 640, 
  "xaxis": {
    "anchor": "y", 
    "domain": [0.0, 1.0], 
    "mirror": "ticks", 
    "nticks": 9, 
    "range": [0.5, 10.5], 
    "showgrid": False, 
    "showline": True, 
    "side": "bottom", 
    "tickfont": {"size": 20.0}, 
    "ticks": "inside", 
    "title": "x-axes", 
    "titlefont": {
      "color": "black", 
      "size": 22.0
    }, 
    "type": "linear", 
    "zeroline": False
  }, 
  "yaxis": {
    "tickmode":'auto',
    "ticks":'outside',
    "tick0":0,
    "dtick":100,
    "ticklen":8,
    "tickwidth":4,
    "anchor": "x",  
    "mirror": "ticks",
    "domain": [0.0, 1.0],
    "nticks": 6,  
    "showgrid": False, 
    "showline": True, 
    "side": "left", 
    "tickfont": {"size": 20.0}, 
    "ticks": "inside", 
    "title": "y-axis",
    "titlefont": {
      "color": "black", 
      "size": 22.0
    }, 
    "type": "log", 
    "zeroline": False,
  }
}
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.plot(fig, filename='"log-no-log"')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers represent the intermediate multiples until you get to the next order of magnitude. The first 3,4,5 etc. represent multiples of 100 until you reach the tick 1000. Then it will be the markers for multiples of 1000 until you reach 10k. Because of the logarithmic scale, they are not drawn equidistand.

So they might be useful if you want to read from the graph what your value at e.g. x=2 is.

Comment: OK.. I can understand but if i want to remove their representation from scale what should i do.?? i have seen a lot of properties of axes in plotly (python) but can't find the way. I just need 1000 and 10k and wanna remove in between values

Comment: What you are using right now are the attributes `tick0` which is the starting value for the ticks and `dtick` which is the distance between ticks. You can specify your very custom ticks with `"tickvals" : [1000, 10000]` and `"ticktext" : ['1k', '10k']`

Comment: Thanks.  I have got that with "nticks" property i had set its value 6 which is huge when i have decreased to 3, it looks better:)